# "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int"

Tags: java

Al crear este method que chequea si el número es positivo o negativo, me da error al compilar.

> "MyClass.java:4: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int"

¿Alguien me podría orientar sobre el error? No necesito que el method devuelva ningún resultado, sólo que haga un print según el número ingresado.

Naturalmente el error desaparece reemplazando el `void` por `int` y agregando un valor de `return`, pero no es lo que busco y no entiendo por qué lo pide.

Gracias desde ya.

```
 public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int test = checkNumber(5);
      test = checkNumber(10);
      test = checkNumber(-1);
     }

     public static void checkNumber(int test){
         if (test > 0) {
             System.out.println("positive");
         } else if (test < 0) {
            System.out.println("negative");
         } else {
             System.out.println("zero");
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu código supone que el método `checkNumber` retorna un numero entero, el método en si no retorna nada.

```
int test = checkNumber(5);
```

Solo invoca el método directo, sin asignarlo a ninguna variable y no deberías tener problemas.

```
checkNumber(5);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora entiendo por qué. Saludos.

Comment: Si te sirve la informacion marca mi respuesta como correcta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se debe a que el método `void` no devuelve ningún valor, cuando cambias `void` por `int` el compilador entiende que recibirás un valor `int` como resultado de la función.

Ahora quita la variable test y solo escribe la función con el parámetro que le envías.

```html
checkNumber(5);
```

Con eso bastaría para resolver tu error.

Dios te bendiga, espero te ayude esto sino puedes comentarme.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, el error indica que tu metodo no retorna un valor, es del tipo `void`,

recordemos que la estructura general de un metodo es la siguiente:

```
tipo-retorno nombre(lista parámetros){
    //cuerpo de método
 }
```

cuando un indicas que tu método es void no va a retornar nada, en tu caso tendría que ser así:

```
 checkNumber(10); // solo ejecutas el metodo y en consola verias el resultado
```